# Shortcut to copy text to clipboard and then search it on safari?

Tags: safari, search, shortcut

is there a shortcut for this:
I'm on Safari and see a term I'd like to google. Maybe an obscure term or something I want more information of (gadget, e.g.)
Now what I do is:

1. I copy the text
2. open a new tab
3. paste the text
4. and press enter.

Is there a shortcut? Like copy+search key combination?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be keyboard shortcut? Because there's builtin context menu called *Search with Google* when You right click on selected text.

Answer (score 1):

Using the built in 'Search With Google' service for **Safari** you can assign it a shortcut key combo.

I had to make sure that the normal service did not have a shortcut. Giving it one here does not work on my 10.10.2 os x

[image]

---

Now add a new **Application** shortcut for **Safari**: Using `Search With Google`  as the Menu title.

[image]

---

[image]

---

You then may have to relaunch Safari for it to pick it up and you can use it.

But now all you need to do is select some text in Safari and use the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the text, right-click and select Search with Google from the contextual menu.

[image]

This can be automated with Keyboard Maestro.